# Change image on row hover in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I am working on a reacts app and the requirement is to change the image on row hover.

There are multiple rows where each row has two columns (name and image). The requirement is to show helmet image only when the row is hovered and when it is not hovered, it should show the camera image.

I am able to change the image when the image column is hovered but **how to change the image when the row is hovered?**

```
<div class="container">
  <div> Name </div>
  <div> 
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" height="30px" width="30px"/> 
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png" height="30px" width="30px"/>
</div>
</div>


.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.container:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: What constitutes a "row" in the html you posted?

Comment: @RobMoll Simply the parent container of the image and name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the `src` property of the image element when hovering over its parent `.container`, you will have to use JavaScript. You can use jQuery to achieve your goal:

```
$('.container').hover(
    () => { // on mouse over
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', '[your new image url]')
    },
    () => { // on mouse out
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', '[your old image url]')
    }
);
```

Have a look at this fiddle to get a better idea of what is happening:
https://jsfiddle.net/g9p834fb/

Edit: this was submitted before you've updated your question.

To simply alternate the images in your row, you only need to update your CSS. See this fiddle for the changes required: https://jsfiddle.net/g9p834fb/1/

The gist is that you can define styles for the images based on the container's state (i.e. hovered, not hovered)

Here's what the updated html looks like:

```
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" height="30px" width="30px" class="default-image"/> 
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png" height="30px" width="30px" class="hover-image"/>
```

As you can see, we use two classes to differentiate between the two states.

You then only need to add these two styles:

```
.container .default-image,
.container:hover .hover-image{
  display: block;
}

.container .hover-image,
.container:hover .default-image{
  display: none;
}
```

That should achieve your desired effect.

Comment: Thank you so much Romi but how can we achieve this in reactjs? Actually jQuery method wont work in my case

Comment: @newbie I've updated my answer. Please have a look and let me know if it is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Not exactly what I am looking. I am not able to explain it in better way so its ok

Comment: @newbie but that is exactly what you've described in your question. `The requirement is to show helmet image only when the row is hovered and when it is not hovered, it should show the camera image.` And that's what the fiddle shows.

Comment: Actually the problem is from my end, I was not able to explain the question. I am making a demo of the actual problem and then I ll repost

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any js to achive this just a simple css hover like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.show-on-hover {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container:hover .show-on-hover {
  display: block;
}

.container:hover .hide-on-hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div> Name </div>
  <div>
    <img class="hide-on-hover" src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" height="30px" width="30px" />
    <img class="show-on-hover" src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png" height="30px" width="30px" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the same solution I've proposed. I've updated my answer after the initial question was updated. You can also simplify your styles.

Comment: Sorry I can't feel it coming that you are going to edit your answer

Comment: Thanks Nico for the help :)